# How can I eliminate this (seemingly) unnecessary clone() call using the sysinfo crate?

Tags: rust, lazy-initialization

I'm using the [lazy-init](https://docs.rs/lazy-init/0.1.1/lazy_init/struct.Lazy.html) and [sysinfo](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.3.13/sysinfo/) crates together. Getting information about a process is quite expensive so I thought I would hide it behind a `Lazy<T>`, in fact a `Lazy<Process>`. So I have a little struct - just focusing on the pertinent bits:

```
pub struct ProgramInfo {
    process: Lazy<Process>
}
```

and a function to get the `Process`:

```
impl ProgramInfo {
    pub fn process(&self) -> &Process {
        self.process.get_or_create(|| {
            let system = System::new();
            let pid = sysinfo::get_current_pid();
            let ref_to_process = system.get_process(pid).unwrap();
            ref_to_process.clone()
    })
}
```

I added the `clone()` to get it to compile, but it bothers me because it appears unnecessary. A second copy of the Process struct is being made simply so that it can be moved into `ProgramInfo.process`. Is there a way of just moving the `Process` referenced by `ref_to_process` instead? I tried changing the last line to just

```
*ref_to_process
```

but that won't compile, giving error "cannot move out of borrowed content".

Comment: Not a solution, but a potential explanation of why `sysinfo` doesn't let you do this: When you create an instance of the `System` struct, [it retrieves all its data up front](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.3.13/src/sysinfo/linux/system.rs.html#100), [storing the process list in a `HashMap`](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.3.13/src/sysinfo/linux/system.rs.html#191). If `System` allowed you to take ownership of one of its `Process` objects, it would have to remove it from the `HashMap`, as it can't have multiple owners. This would mean that the process list wouldn't be correct for later lookups!

Comment: @JoeClay That must be why it is so slow...I have just done an strace on it and I can see it statting every process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a cursory reading of the `sysinfo` crate, the answer is **no**.

There does not appear to be a method which returns anything but references to `Process`; and therefore `System` never relinquishes ownership and it would be unsafe to attempt to steal it...

---

A solution, which seems more palatable to me, would be to change `ProgramInfo` to:

- hold onto a `system: Lazy<System>`,
- query `system` each time for the current PID.

How efficient that is would depend on whether `system` re-reads the process info each time, or not.

---

That being said, from a *purely theoretical standpoint*, you could indeed steal it anyway:

- you can use `ptr::read` to create a copy of the instance,
- then call `mem::forget` on `system` so the `System` instance is **leaked** and thus never destroyed.

I doubt this is what you want, I would certainly never recommend it.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu. My mental model was wrong. When I see the `&` I was thinking "this is a heap allocated object, I just need to get hold of the bits". Thinking of `&` as meaning "is owned by someone else" is what I should be doing.